# non-MFC CalcWindowRect()?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

does anybody know if there is a non-MFC version of this API?

CalcWindowRect()

thanks

Comment: awesome, thx guys. Kind of rushing right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AdjustWindowRectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632667%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1, in fact it's right there in the "See Also" section of `CalcWindowRect`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no exact one-to-one replacement function for it, but [`AdjustWindowRectEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632667%28VS.85%29.aspx) is pretty close.  If using the `CWnd::adjustOutside` flag to account for scroll bars, you'll need to do that adjustment yourself.

For example:

```
// MFC version
RECT desiredClientRect = {0, 0, 640, 480};
myCwnd->CalcWindowRect(&desiredClientRect,
    ignoreScrollBars ? CWnd::adjustBorder : CWnd::adjustOutside);

// Win32 version
RECT desiredClientRect = {0, 0, 640, 480};
DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(myHwnd, GWL_STYLE);
AdjustWindowRectEx(&desiredClientRect,
    dwStyle,
    (GetMenu(myHwnd) != NULL),           // bMenu
    GetWindowLong(myHwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)); // dwExStyle
if(!ignoreScrollBars)
{
    if(dwStyle & WS_HSCROLL)
        desiredClientRect.right += GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXHSCROLL);
    if(dwStyle & WS_VSCROLL)
        desiredClientRect.bottom += GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);
}
```